# How to import product attributes with custom source model in Magmi ?

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, import, magmi

Magmi is great to import bulk products but its does not import attributes with custom source model. Maybe Magmi treat such attributes as table source which is not.

How to tackle this and import such attributes and what will be the format of CSV?

After Googling may be using Magmi plugin like column mapper or Value Replacer may fix this but I couldn't figure it out how to config these plugins.

Ref: http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/magmi/index.php?title=Import_-_CSV_datasource#Magento_Dataflow_format

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a third party module support